# Archivo de configuraciones dinámicas después de build en Angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy intentando hacer un fichero de configuraciones, el cual persista una vez construida la build de producción y el cual pueda modificar y condicione mi código, sin tener que transpilar la aplicación de nuevo (ya que es la build de producción).

El problema que tengo es que, al hacer la build, "hardcodea" las variables en el código y no pasa la referencia de las mismas.

Gracias.

[image: JSON y resultado transpilado]

Comment: Hola user. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Puede poner el  codigo en formato de texto en vez de imagen ?  Mira [ask] para mejorar la calidad de tus preguntas. Un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al final he encontrado una solución. Gracias por contestar.

Solución:

**index.html:** incluyo el script configuraciones.js

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="./assets/configuraciones.js">
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

**configuraciones.js**

```
var configuraciones = {
urlEntorno: 'http://mi.servicio.web',
mostrarLogsConsola: true
}
```

**En cualquier fichero  *.ts**

```
declare var configuraciones: any;

let url = configuraciones.urlEntorno;
```

Comment: Entonces marca la respuesta como "aceptada" para que la pregunta quede registrada como respondida, por favor :)

Answer (score 2):

Estás usando el fichero JSON como una dependencia más de tu aplicación, seguramente lo importas como cualquier otro archivo (con `import {...} from ...` ). Eso hace que el compilador transforme tu JSON en un objecto javascript para ahorrar espacio.

En otras palabras, el compilador considera tu JSON como una lista de constantes ya "harcodeadas" y simplemente las añade al resultado.

Si no quieres que sea así, deberías leer el JSON mediante una llamada AJAX, como un recurso más.